# How do I space out my navigation links when it is position fixed?

Tags: css

Beginner here. When I open my file in a live server, the links are all squished in a single position. I have tried using margin and padding, but it didn't work. How do I space the links when I am using position fixed?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="nav">
<a href="#">About us</a>
<a href="#">Contacts</a>
<a href="#">Support</a>
</div>

a {
position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Use ```position: fixed;``` on the ```nav``` element instead of on each ```anchor``` tag.

Comment: you cant do that because the position is **fixed**, but what u can do is  add **position: fixed** into ur **nav** element and then add some margin to ur **a tags**

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comment, you should apply the fixed position to the nav element not each anchor independently.

```css
body {
  min-height: 300vh;
}

#nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <a href="#">About us</a>
  <a href="#">Contacts</a>
  <a href="#">Support</a>
</div>
```